# How to run a js code on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a website with CSS, html and js. I am trying to auto click a button after the html has run. I have tried two different approaches and neither has worked.
Approach 1:

```
<body>
   ...
   <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Crime', this, '#CFDBD5')" id="defaultOpen">Crime</button>
   <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Campus', this, '#CFDBD5')">Campus</button>
   <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Time', this, '#CFDBD5')">Time</button>
   ...
<script>
    function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
           tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
           tablinks[i].style.color = '#CFDBD5';
        }
        document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
        elmnt.style.color = '#273043';
    }

    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
...
</body>
```

In this approach I was hoping the line `document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();` would do it but it doesn't seem to be running.

Approach 2:
Similar to approach 1 but `<body onload="setUp()">` and `document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();` is in a function called setUp.

Comment: Why not calling `openPage('Crime', this, '#CFDBD5')` instead of executing the event click handler?

Comment: @Ele this comes from the html element that calls the function

Comment: Try: `openPage('Crime', document.getElementById("defaultOpen"), '#CFDBD5')`

Comment: Even if I put a console log statement in the script it doesn't run. When I put that in it doesn't get called. I don't think it is a problem with the way I am calling the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
});
```

Comment: where do I add this? in the script?

Comment: replace your last line with that, in your script

Comment: just added it. Nothing changed. I even added a `console.log("called");` in function and nothing was logged in the console so it isn't getting called

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to call the function `openPage('Crime', this, '#CFDBD5')` directly.

Use the event **[`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)** to execute that function when the DOM is totally loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed"); // This is just for debugging.

  openPage('Crime', this, '#CFDBD5');
  // or document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the file I was working on got copied into a different directory and the file that I was refreshing in the browser was that file not the one I was changing, which explains why nothing was being logged in the console.